# wifi disconects freqently and more

Tags: networking, wireless

I've install Ubuntu mate 3 days ago and before that i was not getting this problem in unity.my wifi disconnects frequently and some message like this shows up [image]
even when my wifi router is on it dose not show it in list oh available wifi connections.(i cant take screen shot of that cause when i click tack screen-shot button the list disappears)thus I've installed fing and shows following result[image]
i am only able to connect wifi again after rebooting.
 my laptop is acer aspire 5742
 and router which provides the wifi is D-link and service provider is BSNL

output of command  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

is

```
rahul@rahul-Aspire-5742:~$  lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [14e4:1692] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] NetLink BCM57780 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe [1025:036d]
Kernel driver in use: tg3
Kernel modules: tg3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:002e] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. T77H167.00 [105b:e034]
Kernel driver in use: ath9k
Kernel modules: ath9k
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 .OP had edited his question